# Remapping keyboard shortcuts to use with international keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, internationalization, language, dvorak

I have been using the french version of a DVORAK keyboard layout, called BÉPO, for several years. However I’m increasingly facing an annoying problem: with the multiplication of Electron apps among other things, where you can’t customize the keyboard shortcuts through the `Keyboard` pane in macOS, there’s several shortcuts I can’t use.

**Two recent examples:**

- in Zotero you press numbers to assign tags to an item, but in the BÉPO layout to type `1` you have to press SHIFT-1, which in Zotero doesn’t trigger anything.
- in the Notion electron ("native") app, you press CMD-[number] to switch between workspaces, and for the same reason as with Zotero this keyboard shortcut doesn’t work.

**What I’ve tried and didn’t work:**

- trying to "re-map" shortcuts with [BetterTouchTools](https://folivora.ai)
- trying to do the same with [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)

I must surely not be the same one facing this issue, since I’ve read many international keyboard layouts are similarly configured (i.e., pressing SHIFT for numbers, etc.) It also happens that some shortcuts that do not even use numbers won’t work for some apps.

Is there any way to re-map keys with another application or by any other way, ideally on a per-app basis? Or any way to do it with the aforementioned apps?

Answer (score 1):

Well finally looks like I didn’t look far enough into Karabiner-Elements.

Using the [complex modifications builder](https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/) I was able to create a modification that applies only to a specific app and transforms a key combination into another one (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> into <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>).

Seems to work perfectly so far.